# How to type class prop in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

Class bindings in Vue can accept strings, arrays and objects, according to the docs at https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html.

When setting up a component to accept a `class` prop (e.g. `someInnerComponentClass`), what is the best type to use for that?

This works if I only pass a string, but I want it to accept arrays and objects as if I were setting it like `:class="['some-class', { 'conditional-class': myFlag }]"` on a root element:

```
const props = defineProps<{ class?: string }>();
```

I could try building up my own type that accepts strings, arrays of strings, arrays of objects, etc. but I feel like there's already a type that captures this that I can import, no?

My IDE (WebStorm) sees the class prop as a regular attribute:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any type in Vue's core that is usable but we can use the information of the documentation to make up our own type. It can either be:

- `string`
- `Record<string, boolean>` (Object syntax)
- `(string | Record<string, boolean>)[]` (Combined)

So you could do something like:

```
type Class = string | Record<string, boolean> | (string | Record<string, boolean>)[];

const props = defineProps<{ class?: Class }>();
```

Answer (score -1):

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#accessing-fallthrough-attributes-in-javascript

You shouldn't type `class` as a prop, as it is inherited by default

(and added to root element, see https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance to bypass)

```
<script setup>
import { useAttrs } from 'vue'

const attrs = useAttrs()
const klass = attrs.class
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'm familiar with fallthrough attributes and agree that this is how it should be done in the case you outlined. But, this solution doesn't apply when I need to apply classes to a non-root/"non-attrs-spread" element, or apply different classes to more than one element, as is my case.

Comment: You mean, [#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/attrs.html#attribute-inheritance-on-multiple-root-nodes) ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I need to be able to have the class attribute fall through and be applied to the root element as usual, but I also need to accept another class prop, for example `someInnerComponentClass`, that is applied to some nested element (not a root node). So I was just looking to know if there's a nice way to assign a type to that.

Comment: This component is already set up. If this were a new component or I was doing a refactor I might find a way to not have to rely on this class prop; but since it's already been set up in the way I described above I was curious about how it might be typed, as in our codebase I think it was just set to `string` (which is fine too).